# How do I keep a div at position upon dynamically changing border-width/div size?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a project, in which I need a div at fixed coordinates (say center x, and center y) upon changing the border-width or div width or height.

I've already tried using position: absolute, left, top coordinates but the div shifts from its position on increasing/decreasing div border size, div size

```js
var div = document.getElementsByClassName('center')[0];
function fn(){
    div.style.borderWidth = '10px';
    div.style.borderColor = 'yellow';
}

function fn2(){
    div.style.borderWidth = '1px';
}
```

```css
.center {
    position: fixed;
    left: 100px;
    top: 200px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: table-cell;
   border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 70px;
    border: 3px solid green;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: black;
    transition: border-width 1s, border-color 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="center" onclick="fn()">
  <p>I am vertically and horizontally centered.</p>
</div>
<button onclick="fn2()">Click</button>
```

Expected results should be that the div stays at given center coordinates and still change its size dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

**You can center your div vertically and horizontally with or without absolute positioning using flex properties**

This ensures you that this div will not change position when resizing

```js
var div = document.getElementsByClassName('center')[0];
function fn(){
    div.style.borderWidth = '10px';
    div.style.borderColor = 'yellow';
}

function fn2(){
    div.style.borderWidth = '1px';
}
```

```css
.parent{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    height:100vh;
    width:100%;
}
.center {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: table-cell;
   border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 70px;
    border: 3px solid green;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: black;
    transition: border-width 1s, border-color 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="fn2()">Click</button>
<div class="parent">
<div class="center" onclick="fn()">
  <p>I am vertically and horizontally centered.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @th31 this is exactly what I needed :)